# "no module available" when importing AdColony in the AppDelegate.swift

Tags: swift, adcolony

I've developed an application using Apple Swift but when I try to integrate AdColony in my project when I write this line of code in my AppDelegate.swift:

```
import AdColony
```

I receive the error: no module available.

How can I solve this issue? I've followed all the steps in the AdColony guide (also integrating the other frameworks).

Comment: did you add the library/framework to the project before writing import? https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-iOS-SDK/wiki/Xcode-Project-Setup

Comment: I've followed all the steps in the guide also including all the frameworks before using import instruction, the guide is relative only to Objective-C and doesn't explain nothing about Apple Swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the AdColony framework is Objective-C-based, you'll need to create a bridging header for your project. Here's Apple’s [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html). You’ll want to look at the section called **Importing Objective-C into Swift**.

Note that you’ll need to import AdColony using Objective-C syntax in the bridging header file itself, not in your Swift classes:

```
#import <AdColony/AdColony.h>
```

Once you’ve accomplished that, the framework will now be visible in any of your Swift classes.

Comment: AdColony please i need help, see this post of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362875/adreward-from-adcolony-not-working-on-swift-2-0-for-some-reason