# AdReward from AdColony not working on Swift 2.0 for some reason

Tags: ios, swift, adcolony

I would like to implement a reward interstitial in my game, but i'm getting a lot of AdColony errors such as: "No fill for ad request" or that my Zone ID is invalid.

To start of, this would be how I configured my AdColony Zone:

```
Zone is active? Yes

Zone Type: Preroll/Interstitial (Gives me "No fill for ad request error")
           Value Exchange/V4VC (Gives me "Zone ID invalid, please check config error")

House Ads: Back Fill

Options: 0 0 1

Development: Show Test Ads Only (Although my app is currently Live)
```

The example they give you with the SDK download, is for Apps not for Games so I tried to kinda translate it for Games, although it wasn't that different, but there might be a problem with my current code.
So this is how I have it in my GameViewController.swift.

```
// Outside I declare a struct
struct Constants
{
    static let adColonyAppID = "app5aab6bb6aaf3xxxxxx"
    static let adColonyZoneID = "vz19959f95bd62xxxxxx"
    static let currencyBalance = "coinAmount"
}

// Inside GameViewController
var ad: AdColonyInterstitial?!
var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.setupAdRewardBanner()
    }

func setupAdRewardBanner() {

        AdColony.configureWithAppID(Constants.adColonyAppID, zoneIDs: [Constants.adColonyZoneID], options: nil,
            completion: {(zones) in

            let zone = zones.first
                zone?.setReward({ (success, name, amount) in
                if (success) {
                    let storage = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                    let wrappedBalance = storage.objectForKey(Constants.currencyBalance)
                    var balance = 0
                    if let nonNilNumWrappedBalance = wrappedBalance as? NSNumber {
                        balance = Int(nonNilNumWrappedBalance.integerValue)
                    }
                    balance = balance + Int(amount)

                    let newBalance: NSNumber = NSNumber(integerLiteral: balance)
                    storage.setValue(newBalance, forKey: Constants.currencyBalance)
                    storage.synchronize()

                    self.updateCurrencyBalance()
                }


            })


           //If the application has been inactive for a while, our ad might have expired so let's add a check for a nil ad object
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameViewController.onBecameActive), name: "onBecameActive", object: nil)

                //AdColony has finished configuring, so let's request an interstitial ad
                self.requestInterstitial()

        })

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameViewController.triggerAdReward), name: "triggerAdReward", object: nil)

        self.updateCurrencyBalance()
    }


    func requestInterstitial()
    {
        //Request an interstitial ad from AdColony
        AdColony.requestInterstitialInZone(Constants.adColonyZoneID, options:nil,

                                     //Handler for successful ad requests
            success:{(newAd) in

                //Once the ad has finished, set the loading state and request a new interstitial
                newAd.setClose({

                    self.requestInterstitial()
                })

                //Interstitials can expire, so we need to handle that event also
                newAd.setExpire( {
                    self.ad = nil


                    self.requestInterstitial()
                })

                //Store a reference to the returned interstitial object
                self.ad = newAd


            },

            //Handler for failed ad requests
            failure:{(error) in
                NSLog("SAMPLE_APP: Request failed with error: " + error.localizedDescription + " and suggestion: " + error.localizedRecoverySuggestion!)
            }
        )
    }

    func triggerAdReward(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        if let ad = self.ad {
            if (!ad!.expired) {
                ad?.showWithPresentingViewController(self)
            }
        }
    }


    func updateCurrencyBalance()
    {
        //Get currency balance from persistent storage and display it
        let storage = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let wrappedBalance = storage.objectForKey(Constants.currencyBalance)
        var balance: Int = 0
        if let nonNilNumWrappedBalance = wrappedBalance as? NSNumber {
            balance = Int(nonNilNumWrappedBalance.integerValue)
        }

        print("current balance ", balance)
        //XXX Run animation of giving user coins and update view
    }

    func onBecameActive()
    {
        //If our ad has expired, request a new interstitial
        if (self.ad == nil) {
            self.requestInterstitial()
        }
    }
```

And then after all that, I call this notification to request the ad interstitial when pressing a button after the user loses in GameScene.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("triggerAdReward", object: nil)
```

I tried debugging, I can't seem to see the code getting inside the `if (success)` block. So there might be an issue there.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

After debugging more, i noticed that it's not advancing with this method

```
self.requestInterstitial()
```

So there might be an issue with my account maybe? Why is not passing through the success and goes through the error block?

The error in the console is :

> SAMPLE_APP: Request failed with error: No fill for ad request and
>   suggestion: Make sure you have configured your zone properly in the
>   control panel: http://clients.adcolony.com.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It seems your code should be working.
- Since you want to implement a reward interstitial, you should set the zone type to V4VC.
- In case it said `"Zone ID invalid, please check config error"`, you should check twice the App id and zone id in the source code and the Adcolony client panel page.
- After you changed the zone type, wait for some time(10 min?)  to test, the server should need time to sync the status.
- Test on device instead of simulator if possible.

Here is the document for v4vc: https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-iOS-SDK-3/wiki/Rewarded-Interstitial-Ads-Quick-Start-Guide

Comment: Thanks for the comment though, yes, i tried everything you said, double/triple-checked everything and still didn't work. I ended up going for Chartboost.. it was waaaay easier to implement, no issues with it, i think i implemented it in less than 15 minutes by following 8 easy steps.

Comment: @msqar Congratulations !